# Age between mild and sharp

Tags: cheese

Mild cheddar is 3-4 months old.

Sharp cheddar is 1 year old.

What do they call the cheese that is between 3-4 months and 1 year?

Comment: For real? You've *never* seen the medium cheddar cheese sitting on almost every grocery store shelf?

Comment: I have never seen medium cheddar at Marcs, Kroger, or any other store I have been to

Comment: @Aaronut Even at places like Kroger, there are still major regional differences in what they stock.

Comment: @Aaronut The worlds a big place, it's different wherever you go. It's not a global standard. Here we have mild, and tasty, and some extra tasty cheddar - that's it!

Comment: @TFD So you don't have "sharp", and this question isn't about your naming scheme.

Comment: All the cheddar I have seen is either mild, sharp, or extra sharp where they follow the standards for it which is 3-4 months for mild, 1 year for sharp, and 2 years for extra sharp. I just don't see medium which is between mild and sharp. I am also in the US so I don't see matured, tasty, and extra tasty.

Comment: @caters Well, my answer is I think about all you can really expect to get - sounds like either there's some just labeled "cheddar" without a descriptor, or else they're just not bothering selling anything in between there, same as they haven't bothered with anything between sharp and extra sharp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US and Canada it's usually called medium, or sometimes doesn't have a descriptive term, it's just cheddar. Either way, if your store has anything in between, it should be pretty obvious.

In the UK, it's still medium, [though names past that are different](http://www.britishcheese.com/cheddar).

If you happen to be in Australia, [there's a different set of names](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/43474/1672) with only mild in common.

Comment: There is no usually, it's not a global standard

Comment: @TFD Let's not get too bogged down in this. If you know of another common name, feel free to suggest it. If you don't, that's just more evidence this is in fact "usually". (And really, the question is in English, asking for English names. If it's near-universal in the US, then that definitely covers the majority of native English speakers. On top of that, he called the more-aged cheese "sharp", not "matured" or anything else - so we're talking about American names.)